# find center position in imageview android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am working on drag and drop mechanism . This is an awesome Blog which helped me with the implementation

https://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview

So i have dragview but i want the touch position in the middle of imageview so that it looks good . How to find the coordinates for middle of the view so that i can pass those coordinates as start position ?

ANy clue on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simple math.

```
ImageView view = .....
int centerX = (view.getLeft() + view.getRight())/2;
int centerY = (view.getTop() + view.getBottom())/2;
```

This will return the center coordinate of the View. It may be off by 1 due to rounding errors.